# How to set a minimum number of epoch in Optuna SuccessiveHalvingPruner()?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, pruning, optuna

I'm using Optuna 2.5 to optimize a couple of hyperparameters on a tf.keras CNN model. I want to use pruning so that the optimization skips the less promising corners of the hyperparameters space. I'm using something like this:

```
study0 = optuna.create_study(study_name=study_name,
                             storage=storage_name,
                             direction='minimize', 
                             sampler=TPESampler(n_startup_trials=25, multivariate=True, seed=123),
                             pruner=optuna.pruners.SuccessiveHalvingPruner(min_resource='auto',
                             reduction_factor=4, min_early_stopping_rate=0),
                             load_if_exists=True)
```

Sometimes the model stops after 2 epochs, some other times it stops after 12 epochs, 48 and so forth. What I want is to ensure that the model always trains at least 30 epochs before being pruned. I guess that the parameter `min_early_stopping_rate` might have some control on this but I've tried to change it from 0 to 30 and then  the models never get pruned. Can someone explain me a bit better than the Optuna documentation, what these parameters in the  `SuccessiveHalvingPruner()` really do (specially `min_early_stopping_rate`)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min_resource`'s explanation on [the documentation](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/optuna.pruners.SuccessiveHalvingPruner.html) says

> A trial is never pruned until it executes `min_resource * reduction_factor ** min_early_stopping_rate` steps.

So, I suppose that we need to replace the value of `min_resource` with a specific number depending on `reduction_factor` and `min_early_stopping_rate`.